# Trouble getting child component to update in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm building a simple CRUD note app and I'm having issues getting the child components to update after simple POST and DELETE api calls to create and delete notes.

Here's the parent component with a simple form and a child component `<NotepadsShowView />` to render the submitted notes.

```
class AuthenticatedHomeView extends Component {
  _handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const { dispatch } = this.props
    const data = {
      title: this.refs.title.value,
      description: this.refs.description.value,
      private: this.refs.private.checked
    }
    dispatch(Actions.createNotepad(this.props.currentUser.id, data))
    this._resetForm()
  }

  _resetForm() {
    this.refs.title.value = ''
    this.refs.description.value = ''
    this.refs.private.checked = true
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={::this._handleSubmit}>
          {/* form removed for clarity */}
        </form>
        <NotepadsShowView/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

and the `NotepadsShowView` child component:

```
class NotepadsShowView extends Component {   
  componentWillMount() {
    const { dispatch, currentUser } = this.props
    dispatch(Actions.fetchNotepads(currentUser.id))
  }

  _renderEachOwnedNotepad() {
    const { ownedNotepads } = this.props
    return ownedNotepads.map((notepad, i) => {
      return <NotepadShowView key={notepad.id} {...notepad} {...this.props}/>
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { isFetchingNotepads } = this.props
    const notepads = this._renderEachOwnedNotepad()
    if (isFetchingNotepads || notepads.length == 0) return null
    return (
      <ul className="notepads-container">
        {notepads}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isFetchingNotepads: state.notepads.fetching,
  currentUser: state.session.currentUser,
  ownedNotepads: state.notepads.ownedNotepads,
  sharedNotepads: state.notepads.sharedNotepads
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(NotepadsShowView)
```

Here is the action creator:

```
const Actions = {
  createNotepad: (userId, data) => {
    return dispatch => {
      httpPost(`/api/v1/users/${userId}/notepads`, {data: data})
      .then(data => {
        dispatch({
          type: CONSTANTS.NOTEPADS_CREATED,
          notepad: data
        })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        error.response.json()
        .then(json => {
          dispatch({
            type: CONSTANTS.NOTEPADS_CREATE_ERROR,
            errors: json.errors,
          })
        })
      })
    }
  },

  fetchNotepads: (userId) => {
    return dispatch => {
      dispatch({
        type: CONSTANTS.NOTEPADS_FETCHING
      })

      httpGet(`/api/v1/users/${userId}/notepads`, {id: userId})
      .then(data => {
        dispatch({
          type: CONSTANTS.NOTEPADS_RECEIVED,
          notepads: data.notepads
        })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        error.response.json()
        .then(json => {
          dispatch({
            type: CONSTANTS.NOTEPADS_ERRORS,
            errors: json.error
          })
        })
      })
    }
  },

  deleteNotepad: (userId, notepadId) => {
    return dispatch => {
      httpDelete(`api/v1/users/${userId}/notepads/${notepadId}`, {id: notepadId})
      .then(data => {
        dispatch({
          type: CONSTANTS.NOTEPADS_OWNED_DELETE,
          id: notepadId
        })
      })
    }
  },
}
```

Here is the reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  ownedNotepads: [],
  fetching: true,
}

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CONSTANTS.NOTEPADS_FETCHING:
      return {
        ...state,
        fetching: true,
      }
    case CONSTANTS.NOTEPADS_RECEIVED:
      return {
        ...state,
        fetching: false,
        ownedNotepads: action.notepads
      }
    case CONSTANTS.NOTEPADS_CREATED:
      return {
        ...state,
        ownedNotepads: [
          ...state.ownedNotepads,
          {
            id: action.id,
            title: action.title,
            description: action.description,
            private: action.private
          }
        ]
      }
    case CONSTANTS.NOTEPADS_OWNED_DELETE:
      const index = state.ownedNotepads.findIndex(note => note.id === action.id)
      return {
        ...state,
        ownedNotepads: [
          ...state.ownedNotepads,
          state.ownedNotepads.slice(0, index),
          state.ownedNotepads.slice(index + 1)
        ]
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

A user submits a new notepad which triggers an POST api call. Server returns the new notepad and the reducer adds the notepad to the Redux state. No issues here. However, when a notepad is created the notepad props are undefined and no new notepads are being shown in the child UI components. They don't know of the update and I assume it's because I'm not handling the state update.

I am using `componentWillMount` (`cWM`) above to fetch the updated notepads state before the initial render. I'm assuming I should use `componentWillReceiveProps` but I understand there will be an infinite loop if I dispatch the `fetchNotepads` action because the dispatch in `cWM` will run again.

My question is how do I update the component props when the Redux state changes? Do I have to use component state? What about the lifecycle methods?

Comment: Post your relevant action and reducer code. Are you using [thunks](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk)? Seems like this stuff should be in the action creators. I'm not well versed on async server thunks so I can't post an answer unfortunately but I think this is your problem.

Comment: Ok I will update the question as soon as I can. I'm using thunk.

Comment: Ok it's updated

Comment: Did you copy-pasted this from your code? Can you verify that adding note is indeed updating your redux store? I see a mismatch from your action data to your reducer in `NOTEPADS_CREATED`. In your action, you are passing the data as `{type:..., notepad: data}` where as your reducer is trying to access it as `action.id, action.title` which should have been `action.notepad.id, action.notepad.title`...

Comment: You're totally right! Good eye. Man how did I look over that. What's funny was the reducer would work but only after I refreshed the page. Weird!